# Why is the return type of Java 8's Function.identity() the same as its input type?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

The original implementation of `Function.identity()` is as follow:

```java
static <T> Function<T> identity() {
    return t -> t;
}
```

Now my question is why didn't the author do something like this:

```java
static <T extends R, R> Function<T, R> identity() {
    return t -> t;
}
```

Is there any specific reason for it? Or is it only because of the the method name (`identity`)? Or they just simply didn't do it?

Comment: because that would not be an identity anymore?

Comment: How often, do you think, would you need this?

Comment: I'm not expert on this, but how do you assert that two things are identical in this context?

Comment: Only once. I was courios why they didn't do it. that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this additional type parameter, you would add another use case for this function; it would not only serve as identity function, but also as widening conversion function.

But normally, you don’t need this. The primary purpose is to pass this predefined function as an argument, where the parameter mandates a `Function`. If the particular API follows the [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2711488) rule, the identity function does already serve well, even if you want to do a widening conversion, e.g.

```
Optional<String> o = Optional.of("text");
Optional<CharSequence> cs = o.map(Function.identity());

List<String> l = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
Map<Serializable, List<String>> map1
    = l.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()));
```

work well with the existing definition.

On the other, having two type parameters complicates the usage when an explicit type is needed, as then, you can’t just write `Function.<String>identity()` but had to write
`Function.<String,String>identity()` which is not only more verbose, but truly looks weird for an *identity* function.